# IQueryable<> dynamic ordering/filtering with GetValue fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to filter results from a database using Entity Framework CTP5. Here is my current method.

```
IQueryable<Form> Forms = DataContext.CreateFormContext().Forms;
foreach(string header in Headers) {
    Forms = Forms.Where(f => f.GetType()
                              .GetProperty(header)
                              .GetValue(f, null)
                              .ToString()
                              .IndexOf(filter,
                                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

However, I found that GetValue doesn't work using Entity Framework. It does when the type if `IEnumerable<>` but not `IQueryable<>`

Is there an alternative I can use to produce the same effect?

Comment: difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable is that Linq for Objects (IEnumerable) takes delegates as parameters and executes code directly so anything that compiles is possible. EF uses IQueryable and its expression parser has limits to what it is able to recognize and parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Like<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string keyword) {
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "param");
    MemberExpression memberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, type.GetProperty(propertyName));

    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant("%" + keyword + "%");
    MethodInfo contains = memberAccess.Type.GetMethod("Contains");

    MethodCallExpression methodExp = Expression.Call(memberAccess, contains, Expression.Constant(keyword));
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodExp, parameter);
    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

You would call it like so

```
Forms = Forms.Like(header, filter);
```

I haven't done any validation of the passed parameters. For instance you have to validate that the Contains method exists on the type of the property you're validating against. So it won't work on an `int` or anything like that.

Comment: This looks promissing...I'll give it a shot