# Using Reflection and LINQ to query the ApplicationDataService

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using the VS Lightswitch ServerApplicationContext to access and modify lightswitch data entities within an ApiController.

Let's say I have a Customer entity, and i can query the collection of customers in the lightswitch db using linq:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = from custs in serverContext.DataWorkspace
                                                             .ApplicationData
                                                             .Customers
                                                             .GetQuery()
                                                             .Execute()
                                  where c.AProperty == aProperty
                                  select custs;
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = 
                        serverContext.DataWorkspace
                                     .ApplicationData
                                     .Customers
                                     .Where(c => c.AProperty == aProperty)
                                     .Execute();
```

This works perfectly.

However, I have many more entities and several projects with different entities in each project and I am trying to create a library to allow me to query `ServerApplicationContext` using reflection.

I have used reflection to get the properties of the `ServerApplicationContext` object, which gives me access to the `EntitySet<T>`, but I can not execute any queries against it.

This is the code as it stands:

```
Type t = serverContext.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pInfo = t.GetProperties();
foreach (var p in pInfo)
{
    // p is equal to {Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntitySet`1[LightSwitchApplication.Customer] Customers}
    MethodInfo mInfo = p.PropertyType.GetMethod("GetQuery");
    var result = mInfo.Invoke(p.PropertyType, null) ; //<-- Error Here
}
```

The error returned  is:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Object does not match target type.

Has anyone had any joy with querying `EntitySets` (including where clauses) using reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where you're trying to invoke the `GetQuery` `MethodInfo` has the wrong target - the way it's currently written it's trying to call a `GetQuery` method on an instance of `System.Type` (obtained from `p.PropertyType`), which isn't going to work. What you need to do is get the instance of your `EntitySet<T>` from `serverContext.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData` first, then invoke the `GetQuery` method on that instance.

```
Type t = serverContext.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pInfo = t.GetProperties();
foreach (var p in pInfo)
{
    // p is equal to {Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntitySet`1[LightSwitchApplication.Customer] Customers}
    MethodInfo mInfo = p.PropertyType.GetMethod("GetQuery");
    var entitySet = p.GetValue(serverContext.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData); // new line
    var result = mInfo.Invoke(entitySet, null); // updated line
}
```

For details on how to put together a dynamic `Where` clause against your `EntitySet<T>`, check out the links in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4799798/2611587.